# range problems needed to solve

Tags: r

I want to combine range, mean and sd using cbind (each has 10 numbers), and I used range function to calculate range for each variable in my dataset. However, the range is atomic, and the output is like this:

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi2Ec.png)

[This is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKa6.png)

```
BAA BAF Data Science
1     1     1
0     0     0
1     0     0
```

In my output, R has separated the range and produced 20 numbers. Line 1 and Line 2 should be the range for my first variable. Does anyone know how to solve this? This is my code below that produced this output:

```
 range_com <- c()  
 mean_com <- c()
 sd_com <- c()
 dyad.realized_subset <- subset(dyad.realized, select=c(BAA,BAF,`Data
 Science`,`Life Science`,Engineer,`Previous Raised`,`Max Raise`,Age,
 Patent,`Committed Amount ($K)`))
 
 range1 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$BAA,na.rm=T) 
 range2 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$BAF,na.rm=T) 
 range3 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$`Data Science`,na.rm=T) 
 range4 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$`Life Science`,na.rm=T) 
 range5 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$Engineer,na.rm=T)  
 range6 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$`Previous Raised`,na.rm=T) 
 range7 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$`Max Raise`,na.rm=T) 
 range8 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$Age,na.rm=T) 
 range9 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$Patent,na.rm=T) 
 range10 <- range(dyad.realized_subset$`Committed Amount ($K)`,na.rm=T)
 
 range_com <-c(range1,range2,range3,range4,range5,range6,range7,range8,range9,range10)
 
 for(i in seq(dyad.realized_subset)){     
 mean_com[i] <- mean(dyad.realized_subset[[i]], na.rm=T)   
 sd_com[i] <- sd(dyad.realized_subset[[i]],na.rm=T) }
 
 
 # Bind and output table ####
 
 desc_dyads <- cbind(range_dyads,mean_dyads,sd_dyads)
```

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data. Also, the code as presented is quite messy and it would be tedious to clean it up for you. Finally, your problem has nothing to do with the Rstudio IDE, please do not tag it.

Comment: Just edited my code!

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Also remove all the `>` from the above so that it is easier for others to copy your code.

Comment: I only gave out three variables because I just want to solve the range problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `sapply` to calculate `mean`, `sd` and `range` for each column in  `dyad.realized_subset` together.

```
t(sapply(dyad.realized_subset, function(x) {
  setNames(c(mean(x), sd(x), toString(range(x))), c('mean', 'sd', 'range'))
})) -> desc_dyads

desc_dyads
```

Comment: Is there a possible way I don't have to split the range?

Comment: How do you want range to look? Something like this 1-10? You can do that but then it would not be a number but a string.

Comment: Yes! Something like 0,1